# Could not Find Installable ISAM sql server OPENDATASOURCE function

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am using following code to link to a access database from sql server 8:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Data Source = D:\Kargozini\arazz\Arazdb.Mdb;Jet OLEDBatabase Password = "MYPASSWORD"' )...TLeavePersonel
```

and when I run the query, I get this error: Could not Find Installable ISAM 
I searched a lot but I did not find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string doesn't look well formed. Maybe something like `SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Data Source=D:\Kargozini\arazz\Arazdb.Mdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MYPASSWORD;')` would work (yours was missing a colon and 'D'.

Have a look [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access#microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0) for more examples of correct Access connection strings. Also, that page mentions

> Some reports of problems with password longer than 14 characters. Also that some characters might cause trouble. If you are having problems, try change password to a short one with normal characters.

So depending on what your password is, that could be an issue.